# Swift UI DatePicker won't update @ObservedObject value

Tags: swift, datepicker, swiftui, combine, observedobject

I am using a class to store a @Published variable but when I try to pass the value chosen on my custom DatePicker to the @ObservedObject in the class I receive the following error:

```
TimePicker(time: self.$time.**timeSelected**)
```

> Cannot convert value of type 'Binding' (aka
> 'Binding') to expected argument type 'TimeModel'

How do I update the @ObservedObject with the picker value?

Full code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var time = TimeModel()

    var body: some View {

        ZStack{
            VStack{
                TimePicker(time: self.$time.timeSelected)
                
                Text("You chose \(time.timeSelected/60) minutes")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}

class TimeModel: ObservableObject{
     @Published var timeSelected: TimeInterval = 1.0
}
    

struct TimePicker: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    @ObservedObject var time = TimeModel()
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIDatePicker {
        let datePicker = UIDatePicker()
        datePicker.datePickerMode = .countDownTimer
        datePicker.addTarget(context.coordinator,
                             action: #selector(Coordinator.updateTime),
                             for: .valueChanged)
        return datePicker
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ datePicker: UIDatePicker, context: Context) {
        datePicker.minuteInterval = 5
        datePicker.countDownDuration = time.timeSelected
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject {
        let parent: TimePicker
        
        init(_ parent: TimePicker) {
            self.parent = parent
        }
        
        @objc func updateTime(datePicker: UIDatePicker) {
            parent.time.timeSelected = datePicker.countDownDuration
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to refer to the *same* `TimeModel` instance.

A solution is to pass the `TimeModel` to the `TimePicker`:

```
struct TimePicker: UIViewRepresentable {
    @ObservedObject var time: TimeModel // <- declare only

    ...
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var time = TimeModel()

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            VStack {
                TimePicker(time: time) // <- pass `TimeModel` here

                Text("You chose \(time.timeSelected / 60) minutes")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

Note that `TimeInterval` specifies time is in *seconds*, not minutes.

This line:

```
@Published var timeSelected: TimeInterval = 1.0
```

actually sets the default time to 1 second.

Comment: Thank for you the quick fix. @pawello2222 why declare and not init the TimeModel under the TimePicker struct?

Comment: @ThomSides You want to refer to the same instance of `TimeModel` in both cases - so it only needs to be created once and then passed around.